# How to insert NULL at the end of string in c

Tags: c

I am talking input using `gets()` function. So, I want to check where string ends. But `NULL` is not inserted at the end of the string as it is inserted by using `scanf()`. So how can I do this?

Comment: It's not `NULL` at the end, but `'\0'`.

Comment: And `\0` is named NUL. By the way, `gets()` is too dangerous, you should replace it with `fgets()`.

Comment: gets() itself insert null character.

Comment: If `gets()` apparently does not put a `\0` at the end of the string, the problem could be somewhere else in your program. The `\0` could be overwritten by an out of bounds index that occurs **after** the call to `gets`.

Comment: read [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) before asking question. It clearly says: `A terminating null character is automatically appended after the characters copied to str.` So apparently you are doing something else completely wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`gets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) absolutely does insert a null terminator.  However, please note that `gets()` is deprecated and should not be used at all.  Use [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead, as it avoids buffer overrun vulnerabilities.

To use `fgets` on standard input:

```
char buffer[256]
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

Comment: @Mr.32: yes, '\0' is an ASCII NUL terminator, and "\0" is a string containing a NUL followed by an implicit second NUL because all C strings have one added on automatically.

Comment: But I am not using files. I have defined an array and taking input by using the function gets().fgets() is used for files.

Comment: @user3493439: There is **no way** to use `gets()` safely, while there *is* a way to use `fgets()` with `stdin` as the third parameter. Really, `gets()` is so toxic that GCC emits a warning *even without warnings enabled*, and it has been officially deprecated from the language standard. **Do not use `gets()`, ever.**

Comment: @user3493439 if you are not using files and giving input by command line still yet gets() will remove your last \n and insert null terminator in string

Comment: @user3493439: You can use `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)` instead of `gets(buf)`.  Passing the size of your buffer is mandatory to avoid buffer overruns.  Note that sizeof() will work if buf is an array whose size is known at compile time; if you're allocating your buffer dynamically you need to pass the size at runtime.

Comment: It should be noted, however, that `fgets()` preserves the newline if it reads one, so you have to handle that yourself.